# No access via NAT/Bridged

Tags: networking, ping, vmware-player, bridged

In my network there is a PC at 192.168.x.1 which is a host for a VMWare client, a telephone at 192.168.x.2 and a Chromecast at 192.168.x.3.

Running the client bridged, I can ping the Chromecast but not the phone. Running it via NAT, I can ping the phone but can't find the Chromecast as it needs to be in the same subnet. In both cases, the internet is accessable from within the VM and the network printer at 192.168.x.4 does its job. Even disabling firewalls won't help accessing the phone. Where could I go on searching for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running it in bridged mode is the correct way to do it, so far is correct.

Do you get different IP in the host and the virtual machine? You should be able to ping from host to virtual and from virtual to host.

Comment: Yes! In bridged mode VM has some 192.168.x.5 - ping is possible from VM to Host and back.

Comment: Could you analyze your network with tcpdump (or wireshark)? - maybe this will tell you where the ping is lost. If you run this on both the PC and the VM maybe there is some clue

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Simsons idea did help: a dump on hosts LAN port revealed outgoing ICMP packages not being answered.
I could not think of phone settings causing the problem,
but now I checked its settings. In fact it was its net mask that had been set to restrict access to a small number of PCs. Adjusting IP numbers made it.